# Making nginx work with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I am trying to run ruby on rails on nginx.

I have setup ruby on rails and installed the passenger gem. I all ready have an nginx running how do I integrate it with ruby on rails.

I enabled this in nginx.conf:

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini; 
passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
```

And also this in my virtual host /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
passenger_enabled on;
```

After this change nginx fails to restart.

Can some one please help me with this I am running ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Are **passenger_root** and **passenger_ruby** the same paths that Passenger setup gave you while installing?

Comment: Did you check your nginx error log?  Usually at `/var/log/nginx/error.log` on Ubuntu...  It usually gives pretty good errors

Answer (score 2):

I will try to explain it step by step. Nginx + RoR + Capistrano

**1. Create a user (if needed)**

```
adduser deployer
```

**2. Move user to sudo users**

```
visudo
deployer ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

**3. Install bash for him**

```
nano /etc/passwd
Меняем /bin/sh на /bin/bash
```

**4. Change ssh-port for security**

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Change Port 22 on Port XXXX (where XXXX is any number)
```

**5. reload ssh**

**6. Enter by ssh with our new user**

```
ssh -p XXXX deployer@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

**7. Update system if needed**

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install curl
```

**8. Install rvm:**

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm requirements
```

**9. Install ruby, postgres, etc..**

**10. Install gem passenger:**

```
gem install passenger
```

**11. Install nginx using passenger**

```
rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

**12. Set swap if needed**

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap bs=1M count=1024
sudo mkswap /swap
sudo swapon /swap
```

**13. Change config of nginx (server section):**

```
server {
      listen 80;
      server_name www.yourhost.com;
      root /somewhere/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
      passenger_enabled on;
      location ^~ /assets/ 
           { gzip_static on; 
           expires max; 
           add_header Cache-Control public; 
      }
 }
```

**14. Clone good script for nginx start/stop/restart if Ubuntu:**

```
git clone https://github.com/vkurennov/rails-nginx-passenger-ubuntu.git
sudo cp nginx/nginx.conf /etc/init.d/nginx.conf
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/nginx/conf
```

**15. Run nginx:**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```

**BOYA!! Check your browser!**

**Let's go to our app!**

**1. gem ‘capistrano’ for depoly**

```
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'rvm-capistrano’
  gem ‘net-ssh’, ‘2.7.0'
end
```

**2. Run:**

```
capify .
```

**Open deploy.rb and set:**

```
set :application, 'app_title'
set :repository,  'app_repo'
```

**5. add:**

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
require "rvm/capistrano"

load 'deploy/assets’

set :port, XXXX
set :use_sudo, false

set :rails_env, :production
set :branch, "master"
set :deploy_to, "/home/deployer/app_title"
set :user, 'deployer'

role :web, "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
```

**6. cap deploy:check**

**7. cap deploy:setup**

```
set :bundle_cmd, "/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/bin/bundle"
set :bundle_dir, "/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451"

set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-2.0.0-p451@global'
```

**8. Recipes for deploy:**

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

**9. Clone ssh-key on server and add to repo**

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

**10. Add gem ‘therubyracer’**

**11. cap deploy:cold**

Boya! I opened for questions if smth is not clear.

Comment: I did follow your steps even after changing the document root to myapp/public nginx still show the default index page!

Comment: Have you restarted nginx after? Also I published my deploy.rb. May be useful: https://gist.github.com/PavelTkachenko/c9c16561c3053be41d9f

Comment: Yes I did restart but no difference

Comment: You did cap deploy:cold